# Show errors in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to make it so that in the VS code I can see the highlighted errors on the right like in PyCharm?

[image]

Comment: Yes. probably using some extensions. can you post an image of pycharm the way you want it to look?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc1xA.png

Comment: they already do, I see red dots in the scrollbar and red lines in the minimap

Comment: I write code in python and I don't have them.